# mypy error: Module has no attribute "__path__"

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, typeshed

I'm trying to correctly annotate types in a function operating on python packages. Empirically, I know that a package has `__path__` attribute. At runtime, both package (a folder with `__init__.py`) and a module (a .py file) have type of `<class 'module'>`, which can be annotated by `types.ModuleType`; however a module has no `__path__` attribute.

Demo using built-ins:

```py
import asyncio
import turtle

print(type(asyncio))  # <class 'module'>
print(type(turtle))  # <class 'module'>

print(asyncio.__path__) # [.../lib/python3.7/asyncio']
print(turtle.__path__)  # AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute '__path__'
```

What is the type of Package and how to annotate it?

Example code:

```py
import types

def foo(x: types.ModuleType) -> str:
    return x.__path__
```

fails upon mypy check with `error: Module has no attribute "__path__"`. Which type should I use to say that only packages, and not modules, should be passed to my function?

Comment: From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages: "It’s important to keep in mind that all packages are modules, but not all modules are packages. Or put another way, packages are just a special kind of module. Specifically, any module that contains a __path__ attribute is considered a package.". That indicates a package has a __path__, but it does not define a module.

Comment: The error, by the way, does not seem to be a mypy error, but simply the error of `x` (turtle) not having the `__path__` attribute.